# PHP's libcurl can't connect to https site

Tags: php, curl, https

I'm having a problem locally (Fedora) that I'm not seeing on my server (RedHat). When using php's curl functions in a script that runs under apache, I can't connect to HTTPS servers. When I run the exact same script from the CLI, it has no trouble connecting. I have no trouble connecting to HTTP servers, only to HTTPS. When I run the exact same script on my RedHat server, it works fine under apache and from the CLI.

Here's the script:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google.com/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo "Result:\n";
var_export($result);
echo "\n\nHeaders:\n";
var_export($headers);

?>
```

---

When I run it under apache, I get this output:

```
Result:
false

Headers:
array (
  'url' => 'https://www.google.com/',
  'content_type' => NULL,
  'http_code' => 0,
  'header_size' => 0,
  'request_size' => 0,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.028444000000000001,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.028337000000000001,
  'connect_time' => 0.040409,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 0,
  'speed_download' => 0,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => -1,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'primary_ip' => '74.125.226.146',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => 443,
  'local_ip' => '192.168.5.197',
  'local_port' => 39900,
)
```

.. and this in the error log:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fdaff4ba4b0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 1 (0x7fdaff4ba4b0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 74.125.226.146...
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.226.146) port 443 (#1)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Unable to initialize NSS database
* Initializing NSS with certpath: none
* Unable to initialize NSS
* Closing connection 1
```

---

When run in the CLI, I get this output:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fb9c7c6b670
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fb9c7c6b670) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.226.148...
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.226.148) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=www.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Dec 11 12:02:58 2013 GMT
*       expire date: Apr 10 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*       common name: www.google.com
*       issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=DQLgUsKrCoWN8Qeo9oAo
< Content-Length: 257
< Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 17:38:21 GMT
* Server GFE/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: GFE/2.0
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
Result:
'<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=DQLgUsKrCoWN8Qeo9oAo">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
'

Headers:
array (
  'url' => 'https://www.google.com/',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'http_code' => 302,
  'header_size' => 259,
  'request_size' => 53,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.210087,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.028376999999999999,
  'connect_time' => 0.041487000000000003,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.19747600000000001,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 257,
  'speed_download' => 1223,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => 257,
  'upload_content_length' => 0,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.210032,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'redirect_url' => 'https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=DQLgUsKrCoWN8Qeo9oAo',
  'primary_ip' => '74.125.226.148',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => 443,
  'local_ip' => '192.168.5.197',
  'local_port' => 50454,
)
```

Any ideas? Thanks. This is PHP 5.5.7.

Comment: I should mention that /bin/curl also works, and that I've tried setting CURLOPT_CAINFO, but that results were the same.

Answer (score 5):

I restarted Apache and the problem went away. I checked my system package install log (/var/log/yum.log) and found that an update to NSS was installed. I guess you're supposed to restart Apache after upgrading.

Comment: I disabled the suexec module at almost the same time that I updated system packages, and then all of a sudden I couldn't curl to https. I jumped to the conclusion that it was the config change and reverted it and restarted httpd, but now I know the restart was the only thing required.

Comment: I would add you have to do a full restart and not graceful from what I saw.

Comment: same issues but after restarting the apache still not working. Should I do a full restart on our server?

Comment: Same issue here. Verified in /var/log/yum.log that some updates were run: openssl, nss, and a few other things. Running "apachectl restart" didn't help, but running "apachectl stop" and then "apachectl start" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the insecure setting in your PHP code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232977/php-curl-k-or-insecure-x).

Also you can try curl from the command line to see if your curl installation works as designed by running the following command in a terminal

```
curl --insecure <your-url>
```

Comment: I'm using it to connect to PayPal, so CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=false isn't an option. Everything at the CLI, including /bin/curl, works even without the --insecure option.

Comment: Thats true, but does it work with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=false, just for a test? Maybe if this works, the Apache PHP combination could not access the public certificates of the hosts you would like to connect to.

Comment: Hm. It didn't even work with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=false. Same output.

Answer (score 0):

Was your php compiled with `--with-open-ssl=/usr/local/ssl` ?
Check that with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
 Look for a box with header, "OpenSSL." If you see it there, then your PHP installation now has SSL support enabled.

[More Info](http://www.ehow.com/how_7340693_configure-ssl-php.html#ixzz2r9PwsPrc)

Comment: I checked both phpinfo(); under apache and php -i. Same results. I don't see --with-open-ssl in either, but I do see:

under OpenSSL:
OpenSSL support => enabled

under 'curl':
SSL Version => NSS/3.15.2