# Spotify WebAPI - cURL PHP vs cmd

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to build a Web application that would enable an user to search for a song in the Spotify's database and if found automatically search for a music video pertaining to that track. To do that I figured I need to learn some basic Spotify API. I've researched Spotify's Web API and wanted to just test if I can get a json response from a simple query (following [this documentation page](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/)).

```
curl -k -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist"
```

Running this from the command prompt gives me the expected result. The problem starts when I want to get the same result from my test php page.

```html
<?php 

 //instantiate an instance of cURL
 $curl = curl_init(); //returns a cURL resource
 
 $spotifyURL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist';
 curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $spotifyURL);
 //send the request and save the response
 $response = curl_exec($curl);

 if($response){
 echo 'Success';
 }else{
 echo 'Failure';
 }
?>
```

The page always displays 'Failure'. There is no json response. I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to PHP/cURL and Spotify WebAPI so I might be missing out on something really obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to disable certificate warnings ([stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232977/php-curl-k-or-insecure-x)) just like I did in the command prompt with the `-k` modifier.

Adding
 `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`
solved the issue