# Convert cli curl to php

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

I'm having a cli curl command to purge an image from varnish.

```
curl -v -k -X PURGE https://www.example.com/assets/image.jpg
```

How can i convert this to php curl?

I've got so far

```
$varnish_curl = curl_init($varnish_url);
curl_setopt($varnish_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); // -v
curl_setopt($varnish_curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); // -X
curl_setopt($varnish_curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PURGE");
curl_exec($varnish_curl);
curl_close($varnish_curl);
```

Can't seem to find any option for -k

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php

Comment: other examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939609/convert-command-line-curl-to-php-curl

Comment: This might work: https://jm42.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the -k

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

check it out : [php curl -k or --insecure, -X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232977/php-curl-k-or-insecure-x)